# .then() callback doesn't wait for the first promise to be triggered

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to implement promises in my code, but I'm having difficulty in grasping some aspects of it - namely the way one promise triggers another one in a chain. Take this, for instance:

HTML:

```
<div class="test"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
const testTag = document.querySelector('.test')

const firstPromise = new Promise((resolve) => {
  testTag.addEventListener('click', () => {
    doSomething()
  })
  resolve()
})

const secondPromise = () => {
  firstPromise.then(() => {
    setTimeout(function () {
      console.log('This log happened 5 seconds after testTag was clicked')
    }, 5000)  
  })
}

secondPromise()
```

But what happens is: the log happens instantly, it never waits for the click event to run. Why is that? Shouldn't a second promise only happen after the first one gets resolved?

Comment: It seems to me you actually meant to resolve the first promise inside the addEventListener callback. Right now the first promise resolves immediately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> the log happens instantly, it never waits for the click event to run.

You call `resolve()` immediately after creating the click event handler.

You don't wait for the click before calling `resolve()`.

```
const firstPromise = new Promise((resolve) => {
  testTag.addEventListener('click', () => {
    doSomething()
    resolve()
  })
})
```

Note that unless `doSomething()` involves removing the event handler, the element might get clicked again causing a second attempt to resolve the promise, which will fail.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I've tried your solution in my code and it worked!